# Mongoose error on promise with save?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When i try to get promise back with save operation on instance of model. i get error: `undefined is not a function`

```
instance.save().exec().then(..)
```

However, if i try to get promise with model like this, then it works.

```
model.find(..).exec().then(..)
```

Is there no way to get promise for save action. Currently i just pass callback to save function. However, for the sake of consistency i'd like to do all db operations in the same manner.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[`Model#save`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) returns a promise, so you should skip the `.exec()`:

```
instance.save().then(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
let mongooseInstance = new MongooseInstance(Obj);
return mongooseInstance
  .save()
  .then(savedObj => {
    if (savedObj) {
      savedObj.someProperty = null;
      success.data = savedObj;
      return Promise.resolve(success);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  });
```

and maybe with a `catch`?

```
mongooseInstance
  .save()
  .then(saved => console.log("saved", saved))
  .catch(err => console.log("err while saving", err));
```